# Connectivity between two items having an intermediate item as the connection in python

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code that i have written which basically describes the flight connectivity having one city in common between the source and the destination. It seems right for most of the test cases but isn't satisfying this particular one.

```
def onehop(lis):
    hop=[]
    for (i,j) in lis:
        for (k,l) in lis:
            if i==k and j!=l:
              return sorted(lis)
            if (i!=k and j!=l)and(i==l or j==k) and (((i,j) not in hop) and ((k,l) not in hop)):
                m=lis.pop(lis.index((i,j)))
                n=lis.pop(lis.index((k,l)))
                hop.extend([m,n])
    for i in range(len(hop)):
        if hop[i][0]>hop[i][1]:
            hop[i]=(hop[i][1],hop[i][0])
    ans=sorted(hop,key=lambda item: (item[0],item[1])) 
    return ans

onehop([(2,3),(1,2),(3,1),(1,3),(3,2),(2,4),(4,1)])
```

Output I expected:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
```

Output I obtained:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1)]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of an input that *does* produce the correct output?

Comment: >>>frequency([1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,5,4,5])                                             
       ([1], [5])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def onehop(lis):
    hop=[]
    for (i,j) in lis:
        for (k,l) in lis:     
            if j==k and i!=l :
                hop.append([i,l])
    unique = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in hop)]
    ans=sorted(unique,key=lambda item: (item[0],item[1]))
    ans1 = [tuple(l) for l in ans]
    return(ans1)
```

Comment: my output is :[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (4, 2), (4, 3)]

Comment: Hope it helps :)

Comment: It seems to be right.Have you tried it for various other test cases?